# I'm getting a problem while install keepass2, Error "Package dependencies cannot be resolved" in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I'm getting a problem while install  Keepass2 in ubuntu 14.04, getting this error

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

Details

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
keepass2: Depends: mono-runtime (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 3.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-system-security4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 3.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 3.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.6.0) but 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

Please help me guys to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing Mono all the dependency related issues are resolved.
I used this following command to install the Mono.

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```